# Validar campos personalizados de classes geradas

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

Para evitar que as validações feitas com *Data Annotations* sejam perdidas se a estrutura da tabela mudar, é necessário que se crie uma outra classe com os campos para a validação e uma classe `partial`, senda que esta úlitma classe referencie a classe gerada pelo *Entity Framework*. E essas classes devem ficar como essas:

**Metadata.cs**

```
namespace BancoDeHoras.Models
{
  public class StatusMetadata
  {
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Nome deve ser preenchido.")]
    public string Nome {set;get;}
  }
}
```

**PartialClasses.cs**

```
namespace BancoDeHoras.Models
{
  [MetadataType(typeof(StatusMetadata))]
  public partial class Status{}
}
```

**Status.cs (classe gerada)**

```
namespace BancoDeHoras.Data
{
  //usings omitidos

  public partial class Status
  {    
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
  }
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Cadastrar(Status status)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            using (BancoDeHorasEntities banco = new BancoDeHorasEntities())
            {
                banco.Entry(status).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;
                banco.SaveChanges();
                TempData["s"] = "Cadastro realizado com sucesso!";
                ModelState.Clear();
                return View();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            TempData["e"] = "Não foi possível cadastrar!";
        }
    }
    return View(status);
}
```

Porém, mesmo vazio o campo `Nome`, `ModelState.isValid` sempre é `true`.
Por que isso acontece? `ModelState.isValid` deveria retornar `false`.

Comment: Já tentou fazer `if (status!= null && ModelState.IsValid) {...}`?

Comment: Tentei, mas ainda assim não foi. O `status` não está vindo nulo.

Comment: Como você está chamando está ACTION no controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro simplesmente ocorreu porque o `namespace` dos arquivos **Metadata.cs** e **PartialClasses.cs** não era o mesmo em que as classes geradas estão (BancoDeHoras.Data).

A solução foi deixar os arquivos **Metadata.cs** e **PartialClasses.cs** com o `namespace BancoDeHoras.Data`.